# How can I change my local image to a file type in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I want to change my local image into file type so I can send it on a api. How can I do it? How can it be done with **react-native-fetch-blob** 
Please help.

This is what I'm trying so far but it gives me a warning that it cannot find the path to the image. And nothing is shown via alert.

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile('../../assets/imgs/profile.jpg', 'base64')
.then((data) => {

  // handle the data ..
  alert(data);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#user-content-upload-example--dropbox-files-upload-api

This example uses drop box.

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload', {
    // dropbox upload headers
    Authorization : "Bearer access-token...",
    'Dropbox-API-Arg': JSON.stringify({
      path : '/img-from-react-native.png',
      mode : 'add',
      autorename : true,
      mute : false
    }),
    'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
    // Change BASE64 encoded data to a file path with prefix `RNFetchBlob-file://`.
    // Or simply wrap the file path with RNFetchBlob.wrap().
  }, RNFetchBlob.wrap(PATH_TO_THE_FILE))
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.text())
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // error handling ..
  })
```

Comment: but I don't want to do it using DropBox. Is there any other solution? Please help

Comment: Then change the example to the url you want, if you don't have API Authorisation, then you can remove that also. The fetch request is just `{method, url, headers, data}`

Comment: if possible can you please give me a small demo where I convert a local image to blob file. I don't how to use this example.

Comment: can you please see my updated code and tell me what could be the problem here. TIA :)